# Android MVP for multiple user roles

Tags: android, design-patterns, mvp

I have an activity that shows some of its content based on a users role.

For example home activity shows add/delete views for manager and show add/delete/edit views for senior manager and I am currently using MVP pattern and I need best design patterns for the presentation layer in my case as I have more than 6 user types and may increase.

Comment: Welcome to SO ...What exactly is your question?  Its just a statement that you have posted...

Comment: How are user types represented in your code?

Answer (score 0):

I just draw my login through coding. Hopefully, It may help you.

> Create a sperate Java class and declare all the UI components with
>   public and static keyword.

```
public class UI {

    public static TextView textView1,textView2;
    public static Button add,delete,edit,commit;
  }
```

> In your MainActivity initialize the UI Components which declared in
>   separate java class.

```
public class MainActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        UI.textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        //.. Intialize one by one there....
     }
}
```

> In your presenter Class make a method named UserType(String user)
>   and start comparing user and set Visibility to UI Components
>   according to the user.

```
 public void UserType(String user){

        if (user.contentEquals("admin")){
            UI.add.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            UI.delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            UI.edit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            UI.commit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }else if (user.contentEquals("user")){
            UI.add.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            UI.delete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            UI.edit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            UI.commit.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: A switch statement is a bit tidier in this case, and it is probably a better idea to use an enum for user types instead of a string. Something like:

`switch (UserType) { 
    case Manager: break;
    case Senior: break;`

Comment: I just draw concept without know the user type so I assumed a String. people can change it according to their code. and switch depends on the user I usually use If statement because It's more secure than switch according to my opinion.